# Django + Python atualizar e não inserir

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, django

Estou usando um filtro para retornar algum estudante e atualizar seus dados, porém quando tento salvar recebo o seguinte erro:

> *Student with this CPF already exists.* e *Student with this RA already exists.*

Minha `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *

def create_student(request):
    form = StudentForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        student = Student.objects.filter(cpf=form.cleaned_data['cpf']).filter(ra=form.cleaned_data['ra']) #<------ONDE FAÇO O FILTRO
        student.cpf = form.cleaned_data['cpf']
        student.ra = form.cleaned_data['ra']
        student.takeComputer = form.cleaned_data['takeComputer']
        student.computerType = form.cleaned_data['computerType']
        student.question = form.cleaned_data['queston']
        student.termAccepted = form.cleaned_data['termAccepted']
        student = form.save() #<------AQUI EU SALVO ELE
        return redirect('registrations:create_student')

    return render(request, 'student-form-registration.html', {'form': form})
```

Minha `Models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Student(models.Model):

    cpf = models.CharField(
        max_length=14, unique = True, verbose_name = 'CPF')
    ra = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, unique= True, verbose_name='RA')
    takeComputer = models.CharField(
        max_length=3, choices=TAKE_COMPUTER_CHOICES, verbose_name='Você levará seu computador pessoal?')
    computerType = models.CharField(
        max_length=7, choices=COMPUTER_TYPE_CHOICES, verbose_name='Qual o sistema operacional do seu notebook?:', blank=True)
    question = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=QUESTI0N_CHOICES, verbose_name='Como a habilidade de saber programar pode ajudar minha carreira?'
    )

    registered = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    termAccepted = models.BooleanField(default=1, verbose_name='Eu li e aceito o uso da minha imagem')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ra
```

Quero atualizar e não inserir

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível saber qual classe base de formulário você está utilizando se é `forms.Form` ou `forms.ModelForm` a questão é se for `forms.Form` o mesmo está tentando salvar uma instância de `Student` que já possui um `CPF` cadastrado o que é impossível visto que você definiu o campo com `unique=True`. Agora se estiver utilizando como base `forms.ModelForm` basta você no `construtor` da classe informar o parâmetro `instance` da seguinte forma:

```
form = StudentForm(request.POST or None, instance = <A instância que será atualizada>)
```

Comment: Olá @ThiagoLuizS, estou usando `forms.ModelForm` então até vi algo parecido com isso que você sugeriu, porém quando faço isso `form = StudentForm(request.POST or None , instance=student) ` recebo a seguinte mensagem: `local variable 'student' referenced before assignment'` sou novo com django e python talvez esteja me perdendo em algum momento

Comment: @RaphaelMeloDeLima para usar a solucão proposta pelo Thiago, você deveria colocar o comando `form = StudentForm(...)` após definir a variável student - o erro que você está se referindo acontece quando tenta-se usar uma variável antes de definí-la - troque a ordem dos seus comandos

Answer (score 2):

`form.save()` salva o *form*, e não o *student*. Como o form possui todos os dados, ele tenta criar um novo registro.

Tente trocar a linha

```
student = form.save()
```

por

```
student.save()
```

Comment: Olá nosklo mesmo alterando a linha, me retorna o mesmo erro

Comment: @RaphaelMeloDeLima tem como colocar o erro completo com traceback? Deve ser algum outro problema, já que usando `student.save()` não há como estar criando novo registro, o erro deveria pelo menos ter mudado.